# Tangents of a Strictly Convex Fuction

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable and strictly convex.  Is it true that $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $x \neq y$ imply
\begin{equation}
f'(x)(y-x) <f(y) - f(x)
\end{equation}
If so, how can we prove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick an arbitrary $x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that $x \neq y$.

Since $f$ is convex (strict convexity not required yet), we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
f'(x)(z-x) \leq f(z) - f(x), \ \ \forall z \in \mathbb R.
\end{equation}
In particular, the inequality holds for $z = tx + (1-t)y$, where $t \in (0,1)$:
\begin{equation}
f'(x)(tx + (1-t)y-x) \leq f(tx + (1-t)y) - f(x).
\end{equation}
We will now analyze both sides of this inequality.
For the LHS, we can simply rearrange terms to obtain
\begin{equation}
f'(x)(tx + (1-t)y-x) = (1-t)f'(x)(y-x).
\end{equation}
For the RHS, we can apply the strict convexity of $f$ and rearrange terms to obtain
\begin{equation}
f(tx + (1-t)y) - f(x)< t(f(x) + (1-t)f(y) - f(x) = (1-t)(f(y) - f(x)).
\end{equation}
Bringing it all together, we have
\begin{equation}
(1-t)f'(x)(y-x) < (1-t)(f(y) - f(x)).
\end{equation}
Since $t \in (0,1)$, this is equivalent to the desired result:
\begin{equation}
f'(x)(y-x) < f(y) - f(x).
\end{equation}

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - The above proof is obviously inspired by your approach, but it seems more direct.  Do you agree?

Comment: The first inequality follows from the following argument: Pick an arbitrary $z \in \mathbb R$.  Then, for any $t \in (0,1)$, by the convexity of $f$, we have $f((1-t)x + ty) \leq (1-t)f(x) + tf(y)$.  Rearranging this inequality gives $\frac{f((1-t)x + ty) - f(x)}{t} = \frac{f(x + t(y-x)) - f(x)}{t} \leq f(y) - f(x)$.  Taking the limit as $t \rightarrow 0$ gives the desired result: $f'(x)(y-x) \leq f(y) - f(x)$.

Comment: Nice, Garrett. I agree.Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is true. An equivalent condition for convexity is that $f(x)$ lies above its tangent at every point. This is precisely the statement that $f'(x) < \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}$, i.e. the derivative should be smaller than the slope of the secant line.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Michael.  I think you are right that these two conditions are equivalent; however, I am struggling to prove that equivalence.

Comment: I can only prove $\le$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yeah, same here.

Comment: If the function is just convex instead of strictly convex then equality can hold.

Comment: Agreed.  But can we show that strict convexity implies the strict inequality?

Comment: yes, Assume we have equality. This is the statement that the tangent line at $x$ intersects the graph of $f$ at some point $y$. For this to happen either we have a straight line segment, which implies we are not strictly convex, or the function is concave at some point.

Comment: Maybe the following leads us to the point: Assume $x < y$ and that $f'(x) = \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$. Assume furthermore that $f'(x) = \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$ for all $z\in (x,y]$. Then $f$ is a line on $[x,y]$, namely $f(t) = f'(x)(t-x) + f(x)$. This should be a contradiction. Hence there exists $z\in (x,y)$ such that $f'(x) < \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$. So, the secant slope between $x$ and $z$ is larger than that between $x$ and $y$, which should be a contradiction, too.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - I like the idea, but I think the second assumption makes the argument unhelpful to us.  Even if we definitively arrive at a contradiction, it may just be that the second assumption is false.  The first may still hold.

Comment: @MichaelMenke - I agree.  Intuitively, this makes sense.  But it is the mechanics of the proof that are alluding me.  Can you show the proof more explicitly?

Comment: @Garrett: Please read carefully. In fact, I showed that the second assumption cannot hold. Therefore there exists some $z\in (x,y)$ such that $f'(x) < \frac{f(z) - f(x)}{z-x}$. Hence $\frac{f(z) - f(x)}{z-x} > \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}$, which leads you to a contradiction. Just set $z = tx + (1-t)y$.

Comment: Lets assume that $f'(x) = 0$ the general case should be extractable from this. Then x is either a minimum, maximum, or inflection point. A maximum implies concavity so that's out. Likewise an inflection point is concave on one side and convex on the other, so that is also out. Therefore x must be a local minimum. If the tangent line at x intersects the graph of f then there must be another point $x_0$ which is a local maximum, and so f would be concave at $x_0$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - My apologies, I read too hastily.  I understand your argument now.